# What's the difference between Ubuntu and backtrack?

Tags: kernel

What's the difference between Ubuntu and backtrack? Like I know it's different Kernels. Is it just a deb system with all installed in it for convenience?

Comment: i'm sorry. my english is bad. the question was edited

Comment: You asked - "Is it just a deb system with all installed in it for convenience?" - You mean Ubuntu or Backtrack ? If you meant  backtrack by 'it' please refer http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I can give only a brief idea as detailed comparison will be beyond a Q&A website.

Backtrack is customised Debian/Ubuntu style linux

As per the website of Backtrack linux it is a 
Penetration Testing and Security Auditing Linux Distribution, thus a specialised Linux distribution which is very good for some specific purposes.

Website further states "BackTrack is a Linux-based penetration testing arsenal that aids security professionals in the ability to perform assessments in a purely native environment dedicated to hacking.". For more details see http://www.backtrack-linux.org/

Now Ubuntu is a general purpose operating system for day to day tasks for common man. It can be used for advanced purposes. But to use it as a 'Penetration Testing and Security Auditing Linux Distribution' you would need to customise it and install specific packages. And backtrack just did that. For more details see http://www.ubuntu.com/

So you would choose a distribution based on your needs. Any specific comparison questions, I would suggest raising more specific questions.

Hope this explains little bit.